# gedit problem when open by terminal

Tags: sudo, gnome-terminal, gedit

when I open terminal and run the command `sudo gedit first.cpp` it shows this error in terminal:

```
(gedit:24589): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/bonny/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
(gedit:24589): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files"
```

Comment: I get these errors too. But that does not cause any visible problems in the application. However, let's see if there's any possible explanation for these messages.

Answer (score 0):

it's because you are running the application in foreground of you'r terminal

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>

then type `jobs` command and check the number of that gedit first.ccp process

type `bg [the number you checked in jobs command ]`

you won't see those warnings anymore.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with background/foreground - read the warning about ownership.

Comment: yes u are right , i just said that way u wont see them anymore

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the warning is that you are running a GUI app with sudo - this can lead to several problems (one of them: you might not be able to log in again, because your `Xauthority` file belongs to `root`).

There used to exist a "graphical" sudo - *gksudo* or *gksu* or *kdesu* which prevented that problem.

With current Ubuntu versions the proper way to execute GUI apps with root permissions is a three step process:

```
sudo -i
gedit first.cpp 
....
exit
```

eplanation:

- create a shell with root permissions
- execute the desired command as root
- Don't forget to **close** that shell again.

---

Upon rereading your question I see that you are using `sudo` just to edit a file in your home directory -- don't  do that, is is neither necessary nor useful.